# Cordova Plugin Development and Updating

Tags: android, cordova

I'm attempting to develop a plugin in Cordova,  which appears to have worked. My app is crashing when I try and run it:

```
W/System.err(12878): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xiaoyi.action

W/System.err(12878):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)

W/System.err(12878):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)

W/System.err(12878):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)

W/System.err(12878):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.instantiatePlugin(PluginManager.java:490)

W/System.err(12878):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:170)

W/System.err(12878):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.startupPlugins(PluginManager.java:98)

W/System.err(12878):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.init(PluginManager.java:87)

W/System.err(12878):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.init(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:116)

W/System.err(12878):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:144)

W/System.err(12878):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(CordovaActivity.java:214)

W/System.err(12878):    at com.ionicframework.beekcontrolapp845287.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)

W/System.err(12878):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)

W/System.err(12878):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)

W/System.err(12878):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)

W/System.err(12878):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)

W/System.err(12878):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)

W/System.err(12878):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)

W/System.err(12878):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

W/System.err(12878):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)

W/System.err(12878):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)

W/System.err(12878):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

W/System.err(12878):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

W/System.err(12878):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)

W/System.err(12878):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)

W/System.err(12878):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

W/System.err(12878): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xiaoyi/action

W/System.err(12878):    ... 25 more

W/System.err(12878): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xiaoyi.action" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
```

This I presume is coming from the plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Cordova Plugin Yi

```
<!-- android -->
<platform name="android">
  <js-module src="www/plugin.js" name="plugin">
    <runs/>

    <clobbers target="XiaomiYi" />
  </js-module>
  <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
    <feature name="CordovaXiaomiYi">
      <param name="android-package" value="com.xiaoyi.action" />
      <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
  </config-file>

  <source-file src="src/android/com/xiaoyi/XiaomiYiCordovaPlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/xiaoyi/action" />
</platform>
```

My question is, how do I work on this? Do I make changes in the plugin directory and remove then re-install the plugin for each attempt - or do I make changes the Android platform folder, or the Cordova/Plugins directory!?

Comment: In my case, i have the `<js-module>` tag outside the `<platform>` tag within the `<plugin>` tag. About your question: I would do the changes in the plugin directory. Remove it, add it, check it works alright after a build and go on. if you do the change under /platform folder, everytime you re going to build your project, you'll have to implement again and again those changes manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks it seems I can edit the Java directly in the platform directly once the plugin is working OK in terms of installation. I'll update the plugin once I've finished.